# How does Gravity compare to the Van der Waals Forces?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, estimation, gas

> [Van der Waals forces' is a general term used to define the attraction of intermolecular forces between molecules. There are two kinds of Van der Waals forces: weak London Dispersion Forces and stronger dipole-dipole forces.](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Intermolecular_Forces/Van_der_Waals_Forces)

The obvious question is why is gravity not counted as a Van der Waals force, to which the obvious answer is that at the molecular level gravity is so weak it is not worth considering. What I was wondering is how weak is gravity in comparison to the Van der Waals forces. In other words, how much stronger would gravity need to be for it to me relevant in intermolecular interactions?

Please do not answer 'The Van der Waals forces change based on material, so your question is unanswerable.' I am well aware that the Van der Waals forces are characterized by the constants *a*, which accounts for the intermolecular forces, and *b*, which accounts for molecules not being point-masses, and that these constants are dependent on the material in question. However, between the highly inert and small helium and the highly polar and large water, [*a* only changes by 2 orders of magnitude and *b* is almost identical](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/waal.html). Since the Van der Waals forces do not change by a lot between materials and I am only asking for a rough estimation to give a sense of scale, this is a valid question.

Comment: It appears that you know how to compute a rough estimate of the Van der Waals force between two molecules of your choosing at some distance of your choosing. Is there something preventing you from also estimating the gravitational force between them?

Comment: If one insists on e.g. calculating a ratio of two forces in Newtons, one must also consider the length scale, since a van der Waals force behaves more like $r^{-7}$ than $r^{-2}$.